# jqplot 1 month failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

For some reason jqplot is not rendering the label correctly and, ultimately, shoving all the line points at the end of the chart. Here is what it looks like...

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Below is the JS including the plot point...

```
var _a212064_plot_properties;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    _a212064_plot_properties =
    {
        "legend" :
        {
            "show" : true
        },
        "series" : [
            {
                "label" : "Current Year"
            },
            {
                "label" : "Previous Year"
            }
        ],
        "axes" :
        {
            "xaxis" :
            {
                "tickOptions" :
                {
                    "formatString" : "%b"
                },
                "label" : "Date",
                "min" : "07\/01\/2012 00:00:00",
                "tickInterval" : "1 Month",
                "renderer" : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                "properties" : "xaxis"
            },
            "yaxis" :
            {
                "tickRenderer" : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                "tickOptions" :
                {
                    "angle" : -30,
                    "labelPosition" : "middle"
                },
                "labelRenderer" : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                "labelOptions" :
                {
                    "fontSize" : "13pt"
                },
                "label" : "Organic Visits",
                "properties" : "yaxis"
            }
        },
        "highlighter" :
        {
            "bringSeriesToFront" : true,
            "tooltipLocation" : "n",
            "tooltipOffset" : "0",
            "formatString" : "Point <\/span>%s: %s<\/strong><\/div>"
        },
        "cursor" :
        {
            "show" : true,
            "zoom" : true
        }
    }

    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    $.jqplot.config.defaultHeight = 300;
    $.jqplot.config.defaultWidth = 400;
    _a212064 = $.jqplot("a212064", [[[1341115200, 2330], [1343793600, 2768], [1346472000, 2462], [1349064000, 2331], [1351742400, 2198], [1354338000, 2258], [1357016400, 2763], [1359694800, 2399], [1362114000, 2643], [1364788800, 1550], [1367380800, 621], [1370059200, 356]], [[1341115200, 4654], [1343793600, 4105], [1346472000, 4347], [1349064000, 4163], [1351742400, 3849], [1354338000, 5579], [1357016400, 4908], [1359694800, 3690], [1362114000, 2314], [1364788800, 3173], [1367380800, 2608], [1370059200, 2330]]], _a212064_plot_properties);

}
);
```

Any ideas? Getting the dates into that label is the last thing I can't figure out.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made sure the css is included? Also you have spelt Axis wrong, you have it as Axes instead of Axis, which could be just a typo

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the parameters for `xaxis`.

Here is the working copy of your code: [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/CB9fN/2/)

```
var _a212064_plot_properties;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    _a212064_plot_properties =
    {
        "legend" :
        {
            "show" : true
        },
        "series" : [
            {
                "label" : "Current Year"
            },
            {
                "label" : "Previous Year"
            }
        ],
        "axes" :
        {
            "xaxis" :
            {

                "label" : "Date",
                "renderer" : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
            },
            "yaxis" :
            {
                "tickRenderer" : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                "tickOptions" :
                {
                    "angle" : -30,
                    "labelPosition" : "middle"
                },
                "labelRenderer" : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                "labelOptions" :
                {
                    "fontSize" : "13pt"
                },
                "label" : "Organic Visits"
            }
        },
        "highlighter" :
        {
            "bringSeriesToFront" : true,
            "tooltipLocation" : "n",
            "tooltipOffset" : "0",
            "formatString" : "Point <\/span>%s: %s<\/strong><\/div>"
        },
        "cursor" :
        {
            "show" : true,
            "zoom" : true
        }
    }

    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    $.jqplot.config.defaultHeight = 300;
    $.jqplot.config.defaultWidth = 400;
    _a212064 = $.jqplot("a212064", [[[1341115200, 2330], [1343793600, 2768], [1346472000, 2462], [1349064000, 2331], [1351742400, 2198], [1354338000, 2258], [1357016400, 2763], [1359694800, 2399], [1362114000, 2643], [1364788800, 1550], [1367380800, 621], [1370059200, 356]], [[1341115200, 4654], [1343793600, 4105], [1346472000, 4347], [1349064000, 4163], [1351742400, 3849], [1354338000, 5579], [1357016400, 4908], [1359694800, 3690], [1362114000, 2314], [1364788800, 3173], [1367380800, 2608], [1370059200, 2330]]], _a212064_plot_properties);

}
);
```